# How to make sure a downloaded .iso matches a hash value?

Tags: windows, hashing

I have download the .iso file as guided [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38185) and there is part that says to verify the downloaded .iso with CRC or SHA-1 hash value.

> Make sure that the CRC and SHA1 hash values of the downloaded ISO
>   image match these: CRC: E94C762E SHA-1:
>   F8BE0471FA306E5A9E5C117F63B5D3A621FB571D

How can I get the hash value then?

ps.

My google search comes up with [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/347622/how-can-i-tell-if-a-downloaded-iso-is-complete) and the solution is on MD5.

Comment: This seems to be one tool to do this http://online.morainevalley.edu/websupported/edmartig/msdnaa/isochecksums.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Windows, you can download a utility such as [winhasher](https://code.google.com/p/winhasher/) which will generate various types of checksums for your file. To verify the integrity of your file, compare the checksum to the one on the site you downloaded the software from. If it matches, you're good, if not the software is corrupt, has been tampered with, or a few other things.

To get the md5 sum using native utilities in Linux, use the `md5sum` command like so: `md5sum <liveCDname>.iso` and compare it to the one you found online. Alternatively, if there is a file such as MD5SUMS available for download on the server, you can download it to the same directory as the ISO and run `md5sum -c MD5SUMS`

Answer (score 4):

It should be simple when it comes to Windows, CertUtil is embedded in the OS and doesn't require any special application to install, just run the following based on the hash:

CertUtil -hashfile *filename1.iso* **SHA1**

CertUtil -hashfile *filename2.exe* **SHA256**

CertUtil -hashfile *filename3.txt* **MD5**

Answer (score 3):

## OS X

We can compute SHA-1 and CRC values using the Terminal `shasum` and `crc32` utilities respectively.

```
shasum filename.iso
```

and;

```
crc32 filename.iso
```

## Windows

Install the Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier tool from  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533. Then using `fciv.exe` with Command Prompt.

```
fciv.exe -sha1 filename.iso
```

## Linux

Similar to OS X, we'll use Terminal but the commands are `sha1sum` and `cksum` for SHA-1 and CRC checksum values respectively.

```
sha1sum filename.iso
```

and;

```
cksum filename.iso
```

### Notes

FCIV doesn't appear to compute CRC32 but there are third-party apps available.
For help on further information regarding FCIV, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841290#bookmark-5