# How to cryptographically verify the authenticity and integrity of Microsoft Windows .iso releases (with gpg?)

Tags: windows, authentication, gnupg, pgp, data-integrity

For a given Windows release published by Microsoft, how can I cryptographically verify the authenticity and integrity of the `.iso` file that I downloaded before I copy it onto a USB drive and attempt to install it on my laptop?

Today I wanted to download Microsoft Windows 10, but the download page said nothing about how to cryptographically verify the integrity and authenticity of their release after download.

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO
```

> Note: I don't have Windows, and the page above will dynamically vary depending on if it detects you're running Windows or not. In my case, it instructs me to download the `.iso` from the following link because I'm running Linux
>
> - https://software-download.microsoft.com/db/Win10_20H2_v2_English_x64.iso?t=678f5b15-082a-4efb-8190-adc59cdcea87&e=1612452261&h=3ec44f5c20d933fbf28ffeea4fbfbe0a

I expected to see a message on the download page telling me:

1. The fingerprint of their PGP release signing key,
2. A link to further documentation, and
3. Links to [a] a manifest file (eg `SHA256SUMS`) and [b] a detached signature of that manifest file (eg `SHA256SUMS.asc`, `SHA256SUMS.sig`, `SHA256SUMS.gpg`, etc)

Unfortunately, the only information I found on the download page was how to verify the integrity of the image using a SHA256SUM found in a table on the same page. Obviously, this checks integrity but not authenticity. And it provides no security because it's not out-of-band from the `.iso` itself.

How can I preform cryptographic integrity and authenticity verification with Microsoft Windows `.iso` releases?

Comment: You don’t; Microsoft doesn’t publish a manifest information for ISO files.  The Media Creation Tool would provide the necessary authenticity checks I would imagine since that’s written by Microsoft and distributed by Microsoft and you could verify the integrity of the file based on the hash of the executable itself

Comment: VALID question, but indeed I'd agree with @Ramhound that you simply don't verify it. Likely since Microsoft is closed-source/proprietary, have basic users, & such a big company. Guessing they don't see themselves needing to provide that since they may believe they're done their security due-diligence to stop anything bad & the SW does validations silently in the background

Comment: Please note that I do not yet have Windows, so I can't run the Media Creation Tool. Unless that tool is available for linux and *it* is signed?

Comment: @gregg: The question isn't about stopping anything bad coming from Microsoft; it's about making sure the ISO does in fact come from Microsoft (autenticity) and that it wasn't tampered with during the download (integrity). And Microsoft _do_ always provide at least SHA-1 hashes for integrity-checking their provided ISO images, both on the public Windows 10 site and on the customer download (MSDN and VLCS) sites.

Comment: @user1686 By 'stop anything bad' I mean web server hacks, supply chain attacks, etc. I didn't mean BY Microsoft. Even if MS did everything they could I guess nothing stops a MiM or ISP attack during download so I do think its a valid concern as I said. You mention they have SHA1 hashs which is what the user wants, why didn't you link it?

Comment: @gregg: OP already mentioned that they're useless because they're on the same page as the download link.

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to safely obtain Windows. Today I downloaded a copy of Windows from within my trusty Linux laptop and again the same version of Windows from within another Windows install on someone else's computer. Sadly, the filenames and sizes were widely different and the hashes didn't match. How am I supposed to trust anything from Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

The best way of verifying an ISO is to download it from Microsoft in the
first place (twice if you want to be really sure, although that's somewhat
too much).

Otherwise, you need to depend on the SHA1 hashes. Unfortunately, Microsoft
has removed public access from the MSDN Subscriber Downloads area where it
was possible in the past to look up SHA1 hashes.

If you don't know an MSDN Subscriber that can get for you the SHA1 hash,
you need to depend on third-party websites that list these hashes for you.
Below are two such websites:

- [Microsoft SHA1 Hash Archive from My Visual Studio](https://www.heidoc.net/php/myvsdump.php)
- [TechBench by WZT](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php?lang=en)
  (beware ads)

Have also a look at the post
[ISO image integrity check](https://superuser.com/questions/1531250/iso-image-integrity-check-new-try).

Comment: Pitiful they locked/paywalled the hashes :( Guessing they were locking other content & overlooked that element

Comment: This answer does not provide any info about verifying authenticity or cryptographic integrity. The whole point of this question is to figure out how to make sure that my `.iso` did in-fact come from Microsoft. Also, SHA1 is not secure. I believe the checksums provided by Microsoft are SHA256 hashes. That gives you integrity, but not authenticity.

Comment: Excuse me, but if your disk is identical to the one from Microsoft, what do you care? Files don't come with attached history saying where they were originally. Don't you think your downvote was exaggerated?

Comment: Has been stated Microsoft doesn’t provide a method to verify the authenticity of a Windows ISO.